# Default login credentials for phppgadmin

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Hey guys. I want a situation in which I could point to my phppgadmin url and it opens up without asking for login details i.e. how can I set up phpmyadmin to use a default login credential. Or how can I increase the amount of time before the session expires. These are straightforward with phpmyadmin. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method like phpmyadmin's `auth='config'` option however http://sourceforge.net/projects/phppgadmin/forums/forum/115884/topic/2026840 might be able to help you.